# Grails: SessionFactory and Session objects accross controllers

Tags: grails

In a grails service, I create and manage a session for callinng methods from an external API, using the session factory of the API to initiate the connection:

1) Service Session objects (service level):

```
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance()
private Session session
```

2) Service getSession method calls

```
def getSession(Map conf) {
        if (session == null) {
            ...

            Object o = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params)
            session = o.createSession()
        }
        session
}
```

3) A service connector which is called from controller

```
def connect() {

<some logic>
        return session
    }
```

4) In controllers, I retrieve the session object  with :

```
def session = service.connect()
```

Once the session object has been created by the first connection, what is the best way to share it between controllers (even outside from the grails plugin) ?
How to be sure that the session object is called as a singleton  (i.e avoiding each controllers' methods calls to re-initialize the sessionFactory call in the service) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails already have a `SessionFactory` bean, you can just declare it and dependency injection will handle it for you.

Regarding the use of the same session between controllers, how you will handle concurrent requests from different users?

Some thoughts:

- If your external API are have hibernate classes, you can [map them with xml](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html).
- If your external API needs a SessionFactory, just declare it in your services
- If you need the current session, just use [withSession](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withSession.html).

Example of dependency injection:

```
class MyService {
  def sessionFactory
  ...
}
```

Comment: Considering I'm creating a static final SessionFactory instance in a servic ( as well with static getters for session objects), that design should handle concurrent requests safely, what would you suggest otherwise  ? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this static methods?

Comment: I would like to ensure to create the session factory as a singleton, it would assert that only a single session has been created an can be reused accross controllers.

Comment: If you have a single instance of hibernate session you cannot handle concurrent requests of different users. Can you share an effective example where this will be useful to you?

Comment: https://github.com/webvibes/grails-opencmis/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/opencmis/CmisConnectorService.groovy

Comment: This is the grais-plugin I'm currently writing, any help is welcome.

Comment: Hibernate plugin opens and close the session for each request, you could configure a SessionFactory Spring Bean to your connector and always use it to get the new session. You can see how the grails plugin does here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate-plugin